# Database programming with ADO

Tags: database, ms-access, delphi-7, ado

I have two tables in MS Access which I connected with ADOTables in Delphi 7. The relevant fields in the first one are 'Question_id' and 'Question', and in the other one are 'Answer' and 'Question number'. I added a foreign key (relationship) between  'Question_id' and 'Question number' so I would connect answers and questions (it's a test app).
I want to display a question and the answers that belong to that question. Is there a way to display data (with DBEDits maybe) when the fields 'Question_id' and 'Question_number' are equal? I can't find a way

Comment: Write a query that contains a WHERE clause such as `WHERE Question_ID = Question_Number`.

Comment: Have a look at [Master-Detail-Relationships](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_Master-Detail_Relationships)